Problem with integration $\displaystyle \int\frac{dx}{3x^2+5x+4}$
I am trying to integrate the following :
$\displaystyle \int f(x)dx =  \int \frac{dx}{3x^2+5x+4}$ 
Trying tosolve it:
$3x^2+5x+4 
= 3\left(x^2+\frac{5}{3}x+\frac{4}{3}\right)=3\left(\left(x+\frac{5}{6}\right)^2-\frac{25}{36}+\frac{4}{3}\right)=\cdots=\frac{23}{12}\left(\left(\frac{6x + 5}{\sqrt{23}}\right)^2+1\right)$
Making $u = \frac{6x+5}{\sqrt{23}}$ then:
$\displaystyle \int f(x)dx = \int\left(\frac{12}{23}\cdot\frac{1}{u^2+1}\right)du = \frac{12}{23}\arctan(u) = \frac{12}{23}\arctan\left(\frac{6x+5}{\sqrt{23}}\right)$
But this is wrong, can anyone help me? Thanks.

OP forgot that $u=\frac{6x+5}{\sqrt{23}}  \Rightarrow du= \frac{6}{\sqrt{23}}dx$ with which OP can obtain the correct answer as
$$
\begin{aligned}
I= & \frac{1}{\frac{23}{12}} \int \frac{d x}{\left(\frac{6 x+5}{\sqrt{23}}\right)^2+1} \\
& =\frac{12}{23} \int \frac{1}{u^2+1} \cdot \frac{d u}{\frac{6}{\sqrt{23}}} \\
& =\frac{2}{\sqrt{23}} \tan ^{-1} u+C \\
& =\frac{2}{\sqrt{23}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{6 x+5}{\sqrt{23}}\right)+C 
\end{aligned}
$$

You did a mistake in calculating the factor which multiplies the arc-tangent. You should get:
$$ I = \frac{2}{\sqrt{23}}\arctan\left(\frac{6x+5}{\sqrt{23}}\right)+C. $$

Plotting both $\displaystyle 3x^2+5x+4$ and $\displaystyle \frac{23}{12}\left(\left(\frac{6x + 5}{\sqrt{23}}\right)^2+1\right)$ gave me the same graph

There are no doubts that this is correct. Now observe that if $f(x)=(6x+5)/\sqrt{23}$, then $f’(x)=6/\sqrt{23}$. So: $$\int\frac{1}{\frac{23}{12}(1+f’(x)^2)}dx=\
=\frac{2}{\sqrt{23}}\int\frac{6/\sqrt{23}}{1+f’(x)^2}dx.$$

I know that this question is being answered by @Lai. But still I want to post one answer. Because I love solving integrals.
Your integral is $$\int\frac{1}{3x^{2}+5x+4}dx$$
Now your integral can be written as $$\int\frac{1}{(\sqrt{3}x)^{2}+2(\sqrt{3}x)(\frac{5}{2\sqrt{3}})+4}dx$$
$$\implies \int\frac{1}{(\sqrt{3}x)^{2}+2(\sqrt{3}x)(\frac{5}{2\sqrt{3}})+(\frac{5}{2\sqrt{3}})^{2}+4-(\frac{5}{2\sqrt{3}})^{2}}dx$$
$$\implies \int\frac{1}{(\sqrt{3}x+\frac{5}{2\sqrt{3}})^{2}+\frac{23}{12}}dx$$
Now substitute $(\sqrt{3}x+\frac{5}{2\sqrt{3}})=u$
Which implies $dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}du$
$$\implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int\frac{1}{u^{2}+\frac{23}{12}}du$$
Now substitute $u=\sqrt{\frac{23}{12}}\tan(z)$
$$\implies du=\sqrt{\frac{23}{12}}\sec^{2}(z)dz$$
$$= \frac{2}{\sqrt{23}}\int dz$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{23}}×\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{23}}u \right)+C$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{23}}×\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{6x+5}{\sqrt{23}} \right)+C$$

I have done it step by step

There is another way to get the result without any change of variable
$$\frac{1}{3x^2+5x+4}=\frac 1{3(x-a)(x-b)}=\frac{1}{3 (a-b)}\Big(\frac 1{x-a}-\frac 1{x-b} \Big) $$ where
$$(a,b)=-\frac {5\pm i\sqrt{23 }}6$$
Integrating
$$I=\int \frac {dx}{3(x-a)(x-b)}=\frac{1}{3 (a-b)}\log \left(\frac{x-a}{x-b}\right)+C$$
Replacing $(a,b)$ by their values
$$I=\frac i {\sqrt {23}}\log \left(\frac{6 x+5+i \sqrt{23}}{6 x+5-i\sqrt{23}}\right)+C$$
Using the logarithmic representation of the arctangent
$$I= \frac{2}{\sqrt{23}}\arctan\left(\frac{6x+5}{\sqrt{23}}\right)+C$$
